# Releasing allocated memory from a class method

Tags: c++-cli

I have a c++-cli class Locator with a function Locate that takes a lot of memory while it is running. At the end of running, most of the memory is released withing the function by releasing the pointers, but there is still some memory that is not deallocated and if I run the program continuously in a lopp, it stacks up. Is there a way to completely remove all the memory that was allocated using the destructor/constructor at the end of the function each time?

```
public ref class Locator

{
public:
Locator() { } 
~Locator()  { } 
Dictionary<String^, array< Byte >^>^ Locate(Dictionary<String^, String^>^ imgParms) 
{ .....  }

private:
int m_HP;


int main ()

{   
Locator r;

Dictionary<String^,String^>^ myDictionary =   gcnew Dictionary<String^,String^>();

Dictionary<String^,List<array<Byte>^>^>^ myResult1 = gcnew  Dictionary<String^,List<array<Byte>^>^>(); 



myResult1=r.Locate(myDictionary,0);

return 0;
```

}

Comment: You havent told us what Locate() is doing. Based on your question your problem seems to originate in this function.

Comment: I was wondering if it is possible to do it regardless of the Locate method. Assign all the variables inside a heap and then delete that heap at the end.

Comment: "delete that heap at the end" i hope you dont mean to call a single operator which will clean the entire heap in one go. Thats not possible.

Answer (score 0):

Call delete() on the objects you create(just like plain C++). Simply dereferencing the pointer will leave the object for the garbage collector to dispose. Ordinarily this is fine, but if you use a lot of memory in your application, you dont want the wait for the GC to release memory. Ensure that your destructors delete all objects allocated by their respective destructors. This is exactly the same as plain C++. C++/CLI classes implicitly inherit the IDisposable interface and the destructors are wrappers for Dispose() so you dont have to define dispose() seprately(If i remember correctly; you can't do that anyway).